# Prove that f is not one to one

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Do I start by assuming that f is one to one to prove that it isnt? I cannot figure this one out!

Comment: What kind of homomorphism is this?

Comment: What structure is this homomorphism preserving?

Comment: Recall that $f$ being one-to-one means "for all $x\neq y$ in the domain, $f(x)\neq f(y)$." Usually the best way to disprove a "for all..." statement is to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T\subset W$ is a linearly dependent set then one has
$$f(v_i)=\sum_{i\ne j}\lambda_jf(v_j)$$ so by linearity $$f(0)=f(v_i-\sum_{i\ne j}\lambda_jv_j)=0$$

This shows that $f$ is not one to one because $v_i-\sum_{i\ne j}\lambda_jv_j\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you start assuming that $f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n)$ are linearly dependent, and you will have a nonzero element $v$ with $f(v)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A 1-1 homomorphism is an isomorphism onto its range. Thus it maps linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets (because these are defined in the language of linear algebra). Cheers